# MSSQL_How to show number's range by a loop?

Tags: sql-server, loops

I am using MSSQL to run a query, however I want to simply my current steps by using a loop.

```
-- My current script
select product, price,price_range
from
        (select
                product,
                price,
                case
                         when price <= 100 then 'upto100'
                         when price between 101 and 200 then '101-200'
                         when price between 201 and 300 then '201-300'
                         when price between 301 and 400 then '301-400'
                         when price between 401 and 500 then '401-500'
                         when price between 501 and 600 then '501-600'
                         when price between 601 and 700 then '601-700'
                         when price between 701 and 800 then '701-800'
                         when price >= 801 then '800+EURO'
                end as price_range
        from DATA) as A
```

Now my script works, it returns me correct result as I wanted:

```
product    price     price_range
shoes      50        upto100
clothes    456       401-500
computer   1500      800+EURO
```

BUT, can I make it simple? Can I somehow use loops instead of 'case...when...then'? Then if segments of price increase, I don't have to write lots of 'case..'.

I tried to use 'declare' and 'while' but didn't get it worked. How to set variable for loops in this case?

Comment: Better to not to use WHLE loop

Comment: What's wrong with your current one? Adding a loop would slow it down and make it complex.

Comment: Current one works fine, because now I only list less than 10 groups. But if in real analysis I would need 50 groups, making a loop would be easier than repeating typing those "when..then.." 50 times

Answer (score 1):

You can't get much simpler than that.  The only thing neater would be to create a table with the price ranges and to join against it instead of hard-coding it in the query.  You should do that if this query is used in multiple places, or rather often.

Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE price_ranges (
   lowest INT,
   highest INT,
   name VARCHAR
)

INSERT INTO price_ranges VALUES (
   (NULL, 100, 'upto100'),
   (101, 201, '101-200),
   ...
   (801, NULL, '801+EURO')
)

SELECT DATA.product, DATA.price, RANGES.name AS price_range
   FROM DATA, 
        price_ranges RANGES
   WHERE (DATA.price >= RANGES.lowest  OR RANGES.lowest IS NULL)
     AND (DATA.price <= RANGES.highest OR RANGES.highest IS NULL)
AS A
```

Comment: I will use this kind of query quite often, so I really wanted to figure it out. Would it be possible, if we set a loop for "101,201,301..." as well? I need more ranges in my real analysis than what I have listed. That's why I wanted to find a simper way instead of hard-coding.

Comment: You really shouldn't think of loops in SQL.  And the right way to use what I showed here is to do the `CREATE` and `INSERT` once, and to repeat the `SELECT` as often as needed.